# How to make a transparent app in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am  new to flutter,I was working on a launcher application for android the only thing that I am not able to achieve is making the app transparent.When I was applying Colors.transparent it always return  black screen not the wallpaper beneath it.Can anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: Could you share your code please.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: can you specify what you want to make transparent?Status Bar Nav Bar?Please always paste code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

First, modify your app's theme to this, in the android project's `res/values/styles.xml`:

```xml
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

Then, add the transparent activity flag to the launching intent:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityLaunchConfigs.BackgroundMode.transparent
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        intent.putExtra("background_mode", transparent.toString())
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

There is also a an older transparent app example in [this](https://github.com/NMateu/flutter_transparent_app) repo.

Comment: While building the app it gives me these errors. Cannot access  'FlutterActivityLaunchConfigs' :it is package private in 'io. Flutter. embedding. android' and Cannot access 'transparent' : it is public in 'BackgroundMode'

Comment: Just copy the string. replace `transparent.toString()` with `"transparent"`. The BackgroundMode enum is public, I don't know why you can't acess it.